nvcc not found even though cuda is installed
I created conda environment as follows:
$ conda create -n Env_py38_torch241_CUDA118 python=3.8

Then I installed some dependencies as follows:
$ conda activate Env_py38_torch241_CUDA118
$ conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia

But while running make.sh script for one of the git repository, it gives me error:
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/miniconda3/envs/Env_py38_torch241_CUDA118/bin/nvcc'

It seems nvcc is simply not there as below command returns only run_nvcc.cmake path but not the actual path of nvcc:
$ find ~/miniconda3/envs/EnvMOT_py38_torch241_CUDA118/ -name *nvcc*
/home/user/miniconda3/envs/EnvMOT_py38_torch241_CUDA118/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Modules_CUDA_fix/upstream/FindCUDA/run_nvcc.cmake

Why nvcc is not installed in my conda environment and how do I get it installed?

I have only limited experience with miniforge3, but an old cuda 11.8 (still) runs native on my 24.04 system.  Maybe cuda was never installed in your conda env?
